# Class 'Automattic\WooCommerce\Client' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a slight problem when trying to use `woocommerce rest api`.

I have next **structure**:

```
...../plugins/woocommerce/
                          save-parsed-products-ajax.php
                          vendor/
                                 automattic/
                                            WooCommerce/
                                                        HttpClient/...
                                                        Client.php
                                 ...
                                 autoload.php
```

**save-parsed-products-ajax.php**

```
<?php

$consumer_key = 'here_is_my_key'; // here was my real valid consumer key
$consumer_secret = 'here_is_secret'; // here was my real consumer secret 

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;


$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://www.mywebsite.ru/', // here was my real website url
    $consumer_key,
    $consumer_secret,
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
        'query_string_auth' => true // Force Basic Authentication as query string true and using under HTTPS
    ]
);

print_r($woocommerce->get('products'));

?>
```

**output**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Automattic\WooCommerce\Client' not found in 
/var/www/u1111184/data/www/mywebsite.ru/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/save-parsed-products- 
ajax.php:11 
Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/u1111184/data/www/mywebsite.ru/wp- 
content/plugins/woocommerce/save-parsed-products-ajax.php on line 11
```

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpQzpEMLMSs) that did same steps I did but my is not working. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
require_once ('..\vendor\autoload.php');

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;


$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://www.mywebsite.ru',
    'ck_****************************************', 
    'cs_****************************************',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
        'query_string_auth' => true
    ]
);
print_r($woocommerce->get('products'));
```

Error will remain same until we do not use exception class

Comment: Why you change require path with adding `use excteption` line? (btw require_once(..\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream ), doesn't work well :(

Comment: @Alexey I have provided you my working code snippet.
To remove this "(btw require_once(..\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream )" error and  test the code, use the full path where an autoload file is placed.

For ex. here is complete path of my autoload file
require_once "/var/www/html/example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/vendor/autoload.php";

Comment: @rajat.gite I tried above code but I am getting `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Automattic\WooCommerce\Client'` .